# How to get the image file name in an http post request

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm pretty new to MVC and I'm trying to get just the file name of the newly selected file.

The html code looks like this:

```
<form action="Url.Action("UploadImage","Util")" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" encoding="multipart/form-data">
<input name="file" type="file" accept="image/*" title="Browse..." />
</form>
```

The .cs function looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public String UploadImage(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
     if(file == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("File");
     return file.FileName;
}
```

What I'm getting back is `data:image/png;base64,add_32x32.png`
and all I want is `add_32x32.png`

How can I get this result?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this just to extract the file name

```
 var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
```

or in other case you can do

```
var name = file.FileName.Split(',')[1].ToString();
```

Comment: Where would that go? It needs to be in the html markup. I debugged the file.FileName and it shows up as add_32x32.png, as it should, but the post request adds in the object type and encoding.

Comment: I mean you have to use path to extract file-name

Comment: what do you mena HTML html you have is fine