# Get Image data from POST request

Tags: c#, http, c#-4.0, http-headers, azure-mobile-services

I have an HTML file

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<FORM name="form1" method="post">
<INPUT type = FILE name="image" action = http://localhost:61189/api/Utility" REQUIRED/> 
<INPUT type = SUBMIT />
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

When Submitted it triggers the POST function of the APIController. 
I want to get the image data to work on. Where in the Request can i get the image data ?

Comment: A quick google will give you answer, here is one link for you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16027693/how-to-get-the-image-file-name-in-an-http-post-request

Comment: In my case the function looks like this public void Post() {}. However the this(APIController) has a HttpRequestMessage object

Comment: you need to look at the recommended way of asking questions on SO and you really need to learn to google.  Here is another link for you: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/03/01/file-upload-and-asp-net-web-api.aspx

Comment: Are you posting data or getting data from the post?  You're question is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Well i found a way of entering data into HTML request using multi-part form request. 
And C# provides good api to deal with such data.